# How do I fix my installation of ATI Catalyst Video Driver in 12.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation

My graphic card is a **Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series**.
I tried the 2 answers from [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) ?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124292/32413)

But unfortunately, it does not work for my **Mobility Radeon HD 4200**

<sub>**Note**

when I raised this question in May 2012, there was only 2 answers to Stephen Myall's question, since then many answers have been added to his post, it is the master post about this subject</sub>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Update of the solution (18 nov 2012)

because new drivers are available in ATI website.
Solution in 12.04LTS is then:

---

### Uninstall ATI driver

```
$ sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh --force   (if file is existing)
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

### Install free driver

```
$ sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 xserver-xorg-core
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

### Reboot

```
$ sudo reboot
```

### Download ATI driver

Check what is your Graphic Card: `lspci -v | grep -A 12 VGA`

Download the appropriate driver for your machine [here from the AMD/ATI Website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) .
File should be something like **amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run**

<sub>If you are looking for old driver 12.6, today (Jan 2015) it is not available anymore in AMD website. Solution is to to search it in [mirror websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=download+mirror+amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.zip).</sub>

Create a folder

```
$ mkdir ~/catalyst12.6/
$ cd ~/catalyst12.6/
```

And move your downloaded driver in it. 
Unzip it if needed.

```
$ unzip amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.zip
```

### Install ATI driver

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases fakeroot libqtgui4
$ sudo chmod +x amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run
$ sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/`lsb_release -sc`
$ sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
$ sudo amdconfig --initial -f
```

### Reboot and Check if installation is successful

```
$ sudo reboot
$ sudo fglrxinfo
   display: :0  screen: 0
   OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
   OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4200 Series 
   OpenGL version string: 3.3.11653 Compatibility Profile Context
```

**It is all good**, as you can see, after last reboot, `fglrxinfo` **displays my ATI Graphic card correctly**.

### Thanks

I found this solution thanks to **Pavel** and [his link](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29)

### Note

I applied successfuly this solution on 3 PCs on 12.04LTS :
- one with a ATI Radeon HD 3400
- one with a ATI Radeon HD 4200
- one with a ATI Radeon HD 4350

Successfully on hybrid ATi Radeon HD 5650/Intel with driver version 12.10, Precise Pangolin 12.04.02 with configuration in BIOS select 'discrete' graphic. (Acer aspire 4745G)

Comment: On Quantal I needed `sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-12.6-legacy-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/quantal` and also `sudo apt-get install python-apport`.

Comment: In my case there's more to it: fglrx crashes on start up -- because (it seems to me that) it is not supported by the 3.5 kernels (yet?). So I can't make use of proprientary catalyst on quantal. I'm thinking about downgrading to `3.2.0-35` kernel. Do You experience the same? Have You switched to quantal?

Comment: no I m still on 12.04. You will perhaps find more help here for 12.10 : http://askubuntu.com/q/204410/32413

Comment: Thanks it's a nice thread. However, I've decided to switch back to 12.04.

Comment: When I install from the deb file it complains about unmet dependancies (lib32gcc1 and libc6-i386) I'm running Quantal 64

Comment: I just needed to force uninstall drivers:
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh --force
. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Still solves the problem almost 2 years later. Nice.

Comment: @kcpr, thanks => I added the option "-- force" in the answer

Answer (score 19):

### EDIT: Old solution (valid from April to August 2012)

The solution described in this answer is based on ATI drivers v12.4 +patch.
Now, since August 2012, ATI drivers v12.6 are available, the way to install these drivers is described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/218894/32413)

---

**The error occurs because Catalyst has not been updated to work with recent 3.2 kernels.**

Check this link:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969827

and do:

1. Uninstall ATI driver
2. Install free driver
3. Reboot
4. Install ATI driver with the patch
5. Reboot

In detail (for 32bit):

```
$ sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
$ sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 xserver-xorg-core
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
$ sudo reboot
$ mkdir ~/catalyst12.4/
$ cd ~/catalyst12.4/
```

Download the appropriate driver for your machine [here from the AMD/ATI Website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) and move it in `~/catalyst12.4/` . File should be something like amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run

```
$ chmod +x amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run
$ ./amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run --extract driver
$ cd ~/catalyst12.4/driver/common/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/
$ wget -O fglrx.patch http://ubuntuone.com/5gNgEmVfzs3ytD5QZ2YGCi
$ patch -p1 < fglrx.patch
$ cd ~/catalyst12.4/driver/
$ ./ati-installer.sh 8.961 --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
$ cd ~/catalyst12.4/
$ sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
$ sudo amdconfig --initial -f
$ sudo reboot
$ fglrxinfo
   display: :0.0  screen: 0
   OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
   OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series
   OpenGL version string: 3.3.11631 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Comment: It worked man ! thank you. I will try tomorrow to take time to complete your answer by describing in detail all the steps I've done.

Comment: I am facing the same problem .. but not able to locate "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" or "/usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh" anywhere. I have raised a [similar question here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175744/x-error-of-failed-request-badrequest-invalid-request-code-or-no-such-operation).

Answer (score 1):

I found that the provided answers would not work for me until I did an additional step. If you are following the detailed instructions and still getting the badrequest error, try the following in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf
```

In my case this file contained a single entry:

```
blacklist fglrx
```

This seems quite diabolical and I don't know what the cause is, but after commenting out this line

```
#blacklist fglrx
```

and rebooting, fglrxinfo now gives the correct output and fgl_glxgears works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reinstall packet "libgl1-mesa-glx:i386". It always gives the same result:

```
update-alternatives: warning: force re-alternatives / usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf, since the group of links i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf broken.
```

Comment: no more problem found since 12-6 driver installer used.
[Used this manual](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29).

Comment: your response is not answer, I would suggest you to publish your own question to make it visible. But anyway you solved your issue, an share an interesting link, thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

fyi: 13.1 shows up as

```
t@t-ubuntu:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5800 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12002 Compatibility Profile Context 9.012
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: will it hurt? I put it in as ref.

Answer (score -2):

1. Remove catalyst center.
2. Repair flrgx.
3. Purge flrgx.
4. Reinstall ati.

Comment: Can you point out to Boris from what he has presented how you came to this conclusion?

Comment: you mean 1. `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh` 2. `sudo apt-get repair flrgx` 3. `sudo apt-get purge flrgx` 4. `sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run` ?

Comment: @Boris, Thats how to do what the answer states.  While it may be the correct answer ( I can't tell) and for others who read this in the future, I think there should be some understanding of how this conclusion was arrived at. it will give other an opportunity to review and validate before you execute.  The risk is yours, Im just trying to be helpful. (ATI Graphics are a tricky business in Linux)

Comment: So I tried, but 2. `apt-get repair` is a not found command. And 3. `sudo apt-get purge flrgx` did not do much because there is no more flrgx after step 1. And at the end re-installing, I get the same error. @Ashu: some explanation would be appreciated please.