# I am experiencing slow performance on my system. How do I diagnose and fix it?

Tags: 12.04, performance

I am using ubuntu 12.04 in my laptop. This is my first experience in ubuntu. I just installed Ubuntu yesterday.
I have dual OS in my laptop. The other OS is Windows 7.

Comparing Windows 7 ubuntu performance is very slow for me.
For example to open the Dash it takes 10 seconds.

What could cause this to happen?

**My hardware:**

```
Intel dual core.  
2 GB ram.  
320 GB hard disk
```

Basically ubuntu is slow or for me only.
I have a good opinion of Windows comparing Window after using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Poor performance is most often hardware related, typically graphics card or sometimes even wireless drivers. Please identify your hardware.

Comment: can you please also add what is your graphic card ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve overall system performance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2194/how-can-i-improve-overall-system-performance)

Comment: Please tell us what your hardware information is. You can install "hardinfo" from the Software Center, and use it to generate a full hardware profile (you can post this on a file hosting site and link here). If you are more experienced, you can use the terminal and run: `lshw > info.txt`. This will put your hardware info in a file in your home folder. Then you can copy and paste the info on pastebin and link it here.

Comment: In fact see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/31625/1992

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 uses more 3D features so if your graphic card is not good enough, it might be seeking memory in your RAM which is also rather low for nowadays usage.

You can swith to a 2D Ubuntu. I think this will work better for you and you will see that the speed at this point is very snappy.

Answer (score 0):

Right, as suggested by Ndefontenay, a workaround to your problem is to login with a different type of session.
The default one is **Ubuntu** session, using Unity 3D, using many 3D features.

Solutions using less 3D features are available.
Install this [[image: Install gnome-session-fallback] gnome-session-fallback](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-session-fallback)

And them you will be able to open a session with **GNOME Classis (No effects)**.
I think that **GNOME Classis (No effects)** is the one using less 3D features.

To select it, just click on the little cog icon.
[image]

Comment: what do you mean exactly by lighter solutions?

Comment: @msPeachy, by "lighter solutions" I mean that the other types of sessions use less 3D graphic features than Ubuntu session with Unity 3D. That is what is experimented on my PC with small hardware configuration.

Comment: He would have to install the others as they are not included (other than Unity 2D). His problem is most likely with his graphics driver.

Comment: OK, I forgot that I installed the `gnome-session-fallback`, I add this step in my answer.

Comment: I have an ATI graphic card too and I faced performance issues with Unity 3D since 12.04. Even after installing correctly the ATI driver (cf http://askubuntu.com/questions/129597/how-do-i-fix-my-installation-of-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts…), I had perfo issue till I used this workaround