# How to install an ati hd 4200 driver and make it work good?

Tags: ati, graphics

I keep wanting to use Ubuntu 12.04 because it looks nice, but it sucks at running my graphics card, under Windows 7 it works fine but under Ubuntu my windows move laggy.

I've tried the `compiz` fix by un-checking vsync and something in open gl but it didn't work.

PC Specs: 
HP
AMD Athlon(tm) 2 X4 635 Processor 2.90 GHz
4.00 gigs of ram
64-bit
ATI RADEON HD 4200

Ubuntu used to work perfect until about 10.10, I think unity or something messed it up, and the post release updates NEVER work, it always says something about jockey messing up

Comment: Did you check out [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/131027/40421)?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use the open source graphics drivers. Meaning, get rid of the AMD Catalyst `fglrx` drivers. Catalyst is very slow and provides a poor desktop experience, especially on Unity. It barely even works. For months it would regularly crash Unity, so consider yourself lucky if it doesn't crash.

You had to have taken some action in order to install `fglrx`; it doesn't come installed by default. The Restricted Drivers app lets you choose to install it, and kind of hints that it'll provide higher performance. Hah! Yeah right. It "makes your windows laggy". :D

The open source graphics drivers at least deliver decent performance with Unity, although you may run into some slowness when playing 3D games. Hopefully you're not into that kind of thing...

The best solution of course is to get an Intel CPU with Ivy Bridge graphics ("3rd Generation Core i7") -- those things **fly** on Ubuntu. Beautiful, fast, and stable. :)

Comment: I agree stay away from propietary drivers unless it is a last resort.

Comment: i guess im just kinda screwed then because im not going to buy another graphics card because in windows 7 the card works flawlessly i can even play portal 2 and in ubuntu i can barely move my windows lol i guess ill try xubuntu or just go to windows 8