# Cannot set up dual monitors due to errors running amdcccle

Tags: multiple-monitors

After I upgraded to 12.04 my dual monitors stopped working. After I try to set it up in Settings/Display I get error:

> The selected configuration for displays could not be applied: required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(3840, 1080), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1920, 1920)
>
> Failed to apply configuration: %s GDBus.Errorrg.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gn ome_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code3: required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(3840, 1080), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1920, 1920)

If I try to edit it in AMD catalyst control center (I run the command `gksu amdcccle`) I get this:

> (process:2955): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
>
> (process:2955): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.3/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init()
>
> (process:2955): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
>
> (process:2955): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

I tried to restore `xorg.conf` many times and start over but did not help. I have an ATI Radeon HD 3450 video card and ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX driver installed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I hope you're sitting down...

So this is an issue I had with my HP laptop and an ATI graphics card.  Essentially, you need to remove your ATI driver and install the latest version from the ATI website.

THe following link is the best explanation of how to do this that I have found and helped me resolve my issue.

I will say, follow it to the letter, checking everything before each step as if you don't, you will be repeating this several times over and will go grey, and, possibly bald from tearing your hair out..

[fix ATI driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129597/how-do-i-fix-my-installation-of-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts)

Hopefully, this will resolve your issue.