# Install AMD catalyst drivers 12.8

Tags: drivers, catalyst

I have a HP g6 2105tx laptop. I have Intel graphics 4000 and AMD Radeon 7670m graphics in it. I want to know how to install the drivers for such hybrid graphics.
I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS with kernel version 3.2.0.23.
I get error of low resolution if i install the AMD Catalyst drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed the AMD drivers (v12.6) for a Radeon HD 4350 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/218894/32413).
But this solution  is based on the availability of drivers in [AMD web site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx).

And unfortunately, in your case, I'm afraid that **there is no driver for a Radeon 7670**

[image]