# how do I fix ati driver issue

Tags: 12.04, ati

I have little knowledge about ubuntu, but I am learning. Recently, my ubuntu 12.04 required that I update. I noticed that it was updating xorg and other things, after the update I was asked to reboot. I did. now when I start that computer up, it cannot detect any display and refuses to boot from usb. I have no idea how to recover my computer. It simply starts in what is akin to the terminal program and ask for my username and password. After that, I can enter commands.

The problem may be because I manually installed drivers by copy pasting from some instructional that I now have no idea where they are, but what it amounts to is that I "built" the drivers. They were working GREAT until this update. I did this because otherwise I was unable to have sound through my hdmi. After I hand built the drivers, they worked great. After this update Ka-blam! nothing...

Also, I had okay-ed lots of update sources (though all of them [xorg and such] were the stable versions, not the unstable update sources)

Please help and thank you in advance. (if this is posted incorrectly or misplace, please let me know what to do)

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

- your ATI drivers may have not been well installed
- and that the free drivers have been removed.

So I suggest you to:

### 1 - uninstall ATI drivers doing this

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

### 2 - install the free drivers

```
$ sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 xserver-xorg-core
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

### 3 - reboot

```
$ sudo reboot
```

### 4 - check if your graphic card works correctly with the free drivers

### 5 - if your problem is solved after step 1 to 4, and you still want to install ATI drivers

Then to get the instructions to re-install your ATI drivers, if your card is a **Radeon HD 3xxx or HD 4xxx**: follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/218894/32413) starting directly at **Download driver** part.

Comment: okay, that is a huge improvement.  I still don't  have super success with the drivers, but I am back in!!  Thank you so much. still have some untangling to do.  I have 5xxx drivers, do you have some idea about that?  Again.  Thank you VERY much!

Comment: wait, it is doing it again and now the instructions don't work.  It keeps wanting me to update... and every time i restart, this happens...

Comment: okay, got it going again.  working through the ati install on the link you gave.  got confused because my graphics say 4xxx/5xxx, but the hdmi sound is with the 4xxx and this is what I have a problem with.

Comment: have you done all steps till 5 (trying to install the ATI drivers) or have you stop to 4? if you tried till 5 I would suggest you to stop at 4.

Comment: to know if you can use the solution in my link (step 5) please edit your question and add the result of this command **lspci -v | grep -A 12 VGA** to know what is your graphic card