# ati catalyst 13.1 driver on 12.04 LTS w/ 3.5.0-25 kernel

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, kernel

I followed this [HotTo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129597/how-do-i-fix-my-installation-of-ati-catalyst-video-driver-in-12-04-lts) and changed the package to the newest one AMD offers.  It all loaded correctly, but in the end the driver wouldn't run.  I see others have success, but as I looked through the comments, I see that someone with an OS and kernel similar to mine couldn't get it working either.  Is this a problem with the kernel and porting support, or should I look for something else?

Answer (score 0):

@Alvin, I have a similar problem with my Radeon HD4890 on 12.04 LTS /3.5.0-26.
The OpenSource driver is working, but the Card is noisy. 
I have found this link in askubuntu, but yet not tried by myself (lucky about system is running)

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide

May it helps, good luck!

Comment: I read it, too.  My display still works and has basic functionality (size), but nothing else.  I run an ATI HD4350 display card.  I may try a couple things on this page later.

Comment: @Somber Soul, I followed your launchpad-link and it works pretty fine for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried this method and got the same result as the original HowTo above, i.e. goes to 'laptop' display with one single resolution available. I have some broken packages and unmet dependencies with xorg.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx for Radeon HD 3xxx and 4xxx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not sure about adding someones ppa w/o knowing who they are or anything about them.  However, this is the type of solution I was looking for and was expecting, just would like it in Canonical supported repos.

Comment: Understand you) Ok, the problem is with your X-Server version, you need to downgrade it. If you don't wanna use this PPA, you could find other way to do it. X version 1.12 is right what you need.

Comment: I got your ppa, but it didn't help me yet.  I loaded it per your concise instructions and all went well, but I really don't know how to proceed after that.  So what I did was go back to the original HowTo above and started with the section following driver removal with this line:./amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run --extract driver.  Then I saw a syntax error on line 4, "wget" where the error said something wrong with the "0" operand like "not found" or "not command" and I didn't know how to go from there so just proceeded down the list and everything else seemed to work, it never loaded

Comment: Ah, could you send me .logs?
Because it's really difficult to understand something what you can't see)

Comment: I solved this problem on Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to come up with it on Raring Ringtail (beta) right now, and it's really hard, because of kernel version.
I passed 12.04 but solution should be same...
Try to remove proprietary driver if any and install legacy driver. Make sure you got linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal. Also check out this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/993427

Comment: I loaded linux-headers-generic-its-quantal, I had it already but updated it. with Synaptic.  I closed the terminal so how to find logs?  I will do it again tomorrow.  Yes, I did know to uninstall any versions of proprietary drivers - I used the HowTo above, the 1st part also used it to restore ubuntu provided as I had driver broken and it went to "laptop' mode only on this desktop.  Thanx for all your help, Soul.

Comment: I can send you logs such as dmesg, but I don't know how, files too big to post here.

Comment: You can send them via mail: gov@e-mail.ua

Comment: that's pretty old link from 2012, older than the original HowTo and much older than catalyst 13.1 which is brand new.  Somber Soul, I sent you dmesg output, did you get it?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Could you send me output of lspci | grep -i VGA too, pls? I installed the same OS (Ubuntu 12.04; 3.5 kernel)

Comment: Somber Soul, just sent the output asked for.

Comment: Well, I don't know.
You downgrading x-server, because legacy drivers won't work with x-server 1.13. Then you installing fglrx-legacy, which patched to work with kernel 3.5. Then you restarting your PC to apply changes. In details:
You should add PPA to downgrade your x-server
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
Then upgrade to apply changes:
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
Then you installing fglrx-legacy, which should be already be patched to work with kernel 3.5 version:
    sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
And rebooting your PC.

Comment: If this didn't work, you must find working patch to fix this.

Comment: yes, this is what all the HowwTo are saying, but it isn't working. I tried the other answer on this page, with the result of winding up with "laptop" mode with one resolution choice.  xorg not working, unmet dependencies. So I removed the driver, but couldn't load because of dependencies problem.  I bet I'm missing a critical library somewhere.

Comment: Somber Soul, I reloaded Ubuntu 12.04.02 with the same image used before, this time I didn't encrypt the home folder initially, which I had done previously.  It loaded the driver as expected and now is enabled and appears to be working trouble free.  I had tried several times before trying your solution with the old installation and maybe some critical files may have been missing or corrupted. It may have been that I didn't execute this line of code: sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases