# Problem installing fglrx drivers 13.1 with kernel 3.4 on ubuntu 12.04.02 x64

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, kernel, fglrx

I have tried to upgrade from kernel 3.2 to kernel 3.4 ([here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/)) and after that installing fglrx drivers 13.1 (compatible up to kernel 3.5). Here are the steps I followed:

1. Removing (purging) existing drivers

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
   ```

   rebooted
2. updated open drivers:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

   rebooted
3. installed some dependencies and then tried to install fglrx drivers:

   ```
   sudo sh amd-driver-installer-*.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise

   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

At this point the installation stuck at:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.4.0-0304-generic
```

nothing happens and I have to stop installation and I need to use dpkg-reconfigure -a.

Can you tell me how install kernel and fglrx drivers in the correct way? Do I need to know anything else to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Frank, I don't know about rolling back the kernel to 3.4, but you need to run this code to establish dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
```

and this if you have 64-bit 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Then you can try this:  https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx  if you have an ATI/AMD graphics card HD 2xxx to HD 4xxx.  Hope this helps. This is all contained in my question: [ati catalyst 13.1 driver on 12.04 LTS w/ 3.5.0-25 kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271010/ati-catalyst-13-1-driver-on-12-04-lts-w-3-5-0-25-kernel)

Comment: thanks but I don't want to downgrade to 3.4 but to upgrade from official kernel 3.2.0-39 to 3.4. And I tried those commands but the problem i still with fglrx on kernel 3.4 as I wrote. I think that fglrx legacy drivers on that launchpad don't work for my ati msi R6870.

Comment: Frank, with Ubuntu 12.04.2 you get kernel 3.5 0-26, that's what I have.  Here is a HowTo from Ubuntu Guide to upgrade kernel.  http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-0411-10  .  don't compile kernels much myself, I just reinstall the whole system.  sorry.

Comment: What do you mean with: with Ubuntu 12.04.2 you get kernel 3.5 0-26? The official default kernel is 3.2.0.39 and I upgraded to 3.4

Comment: Frank, the kernel I got originally on 3-13-13 was 3.5 0-25 for a 32-bit desktop., Yesterday I rebuilt the whole system with the same image connected to the web and it is now 3.5 0-26 is the kernel I got with the 32 bit image I downloaded. However, my laptop built on 11-15-12 is 32-bit kernel 3.2.0-34. It appears they are updating the kernel every few days or so. Are you using standard Ubuntu or Lubuntu, or something else?

Comment: Frank, I check the ATI website and they offer the same proprietary driver for your card as they did mine- but that doesn't guarantee the open source solution will be the same, still its suggestive the solutions may be similar. http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English

Comment: alvin, I have ubuntu with kde 12.04.02 with kernel 3.2.0.39 downloaded last year, I didn't know that the new release had kernel 3.5, I thought they would have release an update to 3.5 for my system. Btw I still don't understand why i can't install fglrx with kernel 3.4, but thanks

Comment: Frank, I installed updates to my laptop, 1st time since December and now I have the same kernel as you on that machine.  I had a problem with my fglrx driver on my desktop and it would not compile the fix I mentioned.  I reloaded the whole system and applied the fix which contains a patch for the newer kernel and it worked right away as stated.  I assume I broken or lost some critical files or libs and it just wouldn't work.  I know this isn't an option people are fond of, but I could not find a way to fix it, except maybe try an older version like 12.6.

Comment: ok thank you for your informations, what patch are you talking about? Btw they say that fglrx 13.1 includes patch for up to 3.5 kernels so I don't know.

Comment: The patch is contained in the same ppa I mentioned in my original answer, https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx.  But it states it is specifically for HD 2xxx through HD 4xxx ATI cards.  I don't know about HD 6xxx series cards, it may not work, even if you start from scratch which would be extremely disappointing.  I'd suggest finding someone with more experience than I with KDE and your card.  Yes, I know they say the patch works for kernels up to the latest.