# Why won't my graphics work in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I'm very new to Ubuntu and to Linux in general, and took the leap and formatted my PC to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS very recently :)

I seem to be having some trouble getting my graphics card to run properly, I looked over what information I could find but I still cannot get it up and running and figured this was a good place to ask for help.

The information I can find on my graphics is as follows:

`lspci` outputs:

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M]
```

I tried using a mixture of the following links:

[How do I fix my installation of ATI Catalyst Video Driver in 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129597/how-do-i-fix-my-installation-of-ati-catalyst-video-driver-in-12-04-lts)

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

[Ubuntu Precise Installation Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide)

But it does not seem to work, since running `fglrxinfo` in terminal gives:

```
display: :0.0
screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 9.0.3)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

All help appreciated.

Edit: 
I have tried the legacy driver from http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip

I also tried the guide at https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx which caused the system to crash (blackscreen, no boot)

Neither seemed to work. I did however reinstall ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and re-tried both with no success.

Reinstalling ubuntu did however fix the broken dependencies problems, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the software from [this link](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip). It is the latest proprietary Linux driver. If that doesn't work, it would be helpful to know the exact video card you have. Also, try updating your software. If that does not work, type sudo apt-get -f to fix dependency issues.

Comment: I tried that but it says it is not activated - I figured I had to try and purge my old driver, but that did not do the trick. I feel like I'm missing something incredibly obvious :p

Comment: Well initially, before I started tampering with the system through the terminal I guess, I selected "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates)" and installed it, rebooted and it said "Driver is installed but not activated"


Now however I get this: Sorry, installation of this driver failed.

Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

Comment: How do I upload that? :P it's fairly long

Comment: Its too long by about 760k characters, and snipping it as 'code' does not let me post that..

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2968115/jockey.log

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no - when I use the lspci command it tells me it's Radeon's 4200 series :/

Update system, sudo apt-update yea?

Comment: Open Update Manager and see if you have any available updates. Also, open the Synaptic Package Manager and see if you have any broken packages. Maybe a kernel module isn't working.

Comment: Update manager has a single package which says a dependency for FGLRX is unmet and thus cannot install, and the Synaptic Package Manager I can't find - just writing it as a search word in Dash Home gives me nothing :/ By the way, appreciate the help, I heard linux users were helpful in general but it's beyond expectation ;)

Comment: Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f


and Apt-get install -f returns:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a9.000-0ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: The dependency is fglrx-updates

Comment: One or more files have been altered since installation.
Uninstall will not be completed. See /etc/ati/fglrx-uninstall.log for details.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a9.000-0ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a9.000-0ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2968115/fglrx-uninstall.log

Comment: One or more files have been altered since installation.
Uninstall will not be completed. See /etc/ati/fglrx-uninstall.log for details.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a9.000-0ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a9.000-0ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Yeah, same message for both 'sudo apt-get install f' and 'sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates'

Comment: Yeah I tried amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run, and running it and it installed, but when I wrote the fglrx command in terminal it responded with what I wrote in the original post - and the the other post I followed through basically said that meant it failed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help though :) Appreciated!

Comment: @Dillmo - please summarise your comments into your answer otherwise its very difficult to understand the current state of your answer.

Comment: @user170974 - the way we respond to queries is by rediting your question.  Please can you summarise what you have tried so far in your question - we can then tidy up by deleting all the comments.  Thanks.

Comment: Apologies. Edited original post.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to fglrx not working on your card. I had the same issue a while back. Install `fglrx-legacy` from this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx

Comment: I tried following your link, and the instructions, and this caused my system to more or less die (could not even boot). 

I figured it might have been because my system was kinda damaged after the stuff I'd tried, so I reinstalled Ubuntu (I had barely done anything since installation, anyway, except updates) and tried once more. Same results. 

My graphics card when I tested it, using this site: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/install-ati-amd-catalyst-drivers-in.html
And the automatic hardware graphics card detection said 5000M Radeon 4200 Mobillity Series. Which mirrors the VGA 5000M / 4200.